# Vault query for cash in flow test not working

Tags: corda

Issuing some cash within a Flow test - the flow returns the transaction with the output showing the correct Cash state. However, when I vault query for cash states, nothing is returned. Am I missing something?

**IssueTokensFlow**

```
@StartableByRPC 
public class IssueTokensFlow extends FlowLogic<SignedTransaction> {

private static Double amount;

public IssueTokensFlow(double amount) {
    this.amount = amount;
}

@Suspendable
@Override
public SignedTransaction call() throws FlowException {

    // We retrieve the notary identity from the network map.
    final Party notary = getServiceHub().getNetworkMapCache().getNotaryIdentities().get(0);

    // Issue cash tokens equal to transfer amount
    AbstractCashFlow.Result cashIssueResult = subFlow(new CashIssueFlow(
            Currencies.DOLLARS(amount), OpaqueBytes.of(Byte.parseByte("1")), notary)
    );

    return cashIssueResult.getStx();
} }
```

**IssueTokenFlow** **Test**

```
@Test
public void testIssueCash() throws Exception {
    IssueTokensFlow flow =
           new IssueTokensFlow(100.00);

    SignedTransaction transaction = a.startFlow(flow).get();
    network.waitQuiescent();

    Cash.State state = (Cash.State) transaction.getTx().getOutputStates().get(0);

    assertEquals(state.getOwner(), chooseIdentity(a.getInfo()));
    assertEquals(state.getAmount().getQuantity(), Currencies.DOLLARS(100.00).getQuantity());
    // Above assertions pass


    QueryCriteria.VaultQueryCriteria criteria = new QueryCriteria.VaultQueryCriteria(Vault.StateStatus.ALL);
    Vault.Page<ContractState> results = a.getServices().getVaultService().queryBy(Cash.State.class, criteria);

    assertTrue(results.getStates().size() > 0);
    // ^ This assertion fails

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Corda 3, whenever you query a node’s database as part of a test (e.g. to extract information from the node’s vault), you must wrap the query in a database transaction, as follows:

```
node.transaction(tx -> {
    // Perform query here.
}
```

So your test would become:

```
@Test
public void testIssueCash() throws Exception {
    IssueTokensFlow2 flow = new IssueTokensFlow2(100.00);

    SignedTransaction transaction = a.startFlow(flow).get();
    network.waitQuiescent();

    Cash.State state = (Cash.State) transaction.getTx().getOutputStates().get(0);

    assertEquals(state.getOwner(), chooseIdentity(a.getInfo()));
    assertEquals(state.getAmount().getQuantity(), Currencies.DOLLARS(100.00).getQuantity());
    // Above assertions pass


    QueryCriteria.VaultQueryCriteria criteria = new QueryCriteria.VaultQueryCriteria(Vault.StateStatus.ALL);
    a.transaction(() -> {
        Vault.Page<ContractState> results = a.getServices().getVaultService().queryBy(Cash.State.class, criteria);
        assertTrue(results.getStates().size() > 0);
        // ^ This assertion doesn't fail :)
        return null;
    });
}
```